# Mesh added to group object while running scene not visible in Threejs

Tags: three.js, mesh, scene

I am trying to add a mesh on an onclick event in a running ThreeJS scene. The mesh shows up when I add it to the scene object. However when I try to add it to an existing group in the scene, the box remains invisible. What am I missing?:

```
  onclick_function(){
    //find group object
    var group = scene.getObjectByName('myGroupName');
    //create box
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
        var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

   //this works:
   //scene.add(obj);
   //however when added to the group object, the box remains invisible:
   group.add(obj);
```

}

Comment: Is the group visible?

Comment: Other objects in the group are visible (that I add when initiating the scene)

Comment: Whoitout the code of the group I’m only guessin, but any position, scale or rotation  from the group will be applied to the object once you add it. So that could make your object to move yo a place you cannot see or too small to see it

Comment: Yes, I thought of that and played around with the position of the group, but it doesn't seem to be the issue. And the scale of the group is just 1, 1, 1.But I am quite a newbie to Three.js, so I was wondering whether I had to call some function to let the renderer know of the existence of the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appeared that the object was indeed out of view, my mistake. Thanks for your attempts to help!